Tesseract with C# not reading a simple text
I have a simple image that I cropped from a PDF file and i removed the borders because it was a table.
I'm trying to OCR the text but its not finding anything.

Im using the code below, and the text is always empty
 using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
 {
     using (var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(imagePath))
     {
         using (var page = engine.Process(img))
         {
             string text = page.GetText();
             Console.WriteLine("Text: \n" + text);
         }
     }
 }

What could be hapenning with this image?

I manage to fix myself by using the line below
 engine.DefaultPageSegMode = PageSegMode.SparseText;

